# Dashes between cells that act as "connectors"?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a table which requires dashes over cell borders, something like this:

-|-

given that "|" is a vertical border, and a dashed line should be in one piece, going over the cell border. Couldn't find the css property anywhere, sorry if it's too easy :D

Comment: Did you look at the extended character set, there maybe something like that

Comment: Maybe 197 in here https://www.lookuptables.com/text/extended-ascii-table

Comment: Hey, thanks! It shows in a printed array, but won't show in a table when I print out the numbers in table cells. At least now I know what to call it ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you could use the ::after pseudoelement and the not last-child selector, like that:

```css
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        td {
            position: relative;
            padding: 0 10px;
        }

        td:not(:last-child)::after {
            position: absolute;
            content: '';
            display: block;
            height: 1px;
            width: 20px;
            background: #000;
            right: -10px;
            top: 50%;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
    <table border="1" >
        <tr>
            <td>Hallo</td>
            <td>Hallo</td>
            <td>Hallo</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: God have mercy, that's it! Thank you so much, gonna go play with it to get the final, desired effect :D